# What should I need to do after a CPU/IGP change in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, intel-cpu

On the next week I'd like to change my cpu from an Intel G3930 to G4600.

What should I need to do and why? Can I change without reinstall anything? Linux can handle this automatic? Do I need for example update the initramfs? I use the IGP, mostly that's worries me.

**Intel Celeron G3930**

- 2 cores, 2 threads
- Intel HD Graphics 610

**Intel Pentium G4600**

- 2 cores, 4 threads
- Intel HD Graphics 630

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Do nothing

I am no expert, but my understanding is, you don't need to do anything to the OS. It should work as before.

## Why?

Intel graphics has open source drivers built right into the kernel. The right driver loads automatically. After the upgrade when you boot Ubuntu, it will work like it did before.

## This is not Windows

Unlike Microsoft Windows, Ubuntu is open-source and free. This means Ubuntu does not care if you install it in one system and then change the system. In Ubuntu there is no equivalent of [Windows Genuine Advantage feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Genuine_Advantage#Features) that checks your CPU, GPU and other hardware to verify that the OS is installed in the computer it was licensed for.

**So, there is no reason to be afraid that if you upgrade your system your operating system will stop working.** Unless the upgrade requires some proprietary driver that is not currently installed.

Hope this helps